# Error: Android SDK requires ADT version 17.0.0 or above

Tags: android

I updated everything in eclipse but when I restart my eclipse I got this error `'Android SDK requires android developer toolkit version 17.0.0 or above'`.

Then I Run software updates in Eclipse (Help > Check for Updates) and update the ADT but it says `'No updates were found.'`. Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Can  you check your android version in androidsdk\tools\lib\plugin.prop

Comment: @KrishnanunniJeevan please make this an answer so that I can set set it as the correct one.

Comment: thanks..sorry i forgot to follow up since I was busy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you check your android version in androidsdk\tools\lib\plugin.prop ?Probably correcting it to your original android version will work

Comment: I change androidsdk\tools\lib\plugin.prop from plugin.version=17.0.0 to plugin.version=16.0.0 then it works. Thanks.

Comment: argh I wish I had found this earlier, could have saved me hours. Happened with version 21 for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do `Window` -> `Android SDK Manager` and update /install packages.  If that doesn't work download the SDK and extract it and then use `Window` - `Preferences` -> `Android` to set the location and then run `Android SDK Manager`